# setting a method in the controller based on requirement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on the `GalleryController` where I am trying to add a method called `setCurrent` that accepts a value and assigns it to
`current`. If no value is passed in, I need to set the `current` to `0`.

Here is what I have written and it doesn't seems to be correct:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('GalleryController', function(){
    this.current = 0;

    this.setCurrent = setCurrent(intValue){
      if(intValue === null){

        this.current = 0;
      }
      else {
        this.current = intValue;
      }
    };

  });

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;
  });

  app.controller('TabController', function(){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(newValue){
      this.tab = newValue;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabName){
      return this.tab === tabName;
    };
  });
```

Should I first set `this.current = intValue`  as stated in the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no value were passed in, then `intValue` would be `undefined`, not `null`. So your function body doesn't work.

Another huge problem here, which I can only hope is a typo, is that you have `setCurrent` where you should have `function`.

I don't understand the question at the end of your post, but this will behave as desired:

```
this.setCurrent = function (intValue) {
   if (!intValue) {
     this.current = 0;
   }
   else {
     this.current = intValue;
   }
};
```

If you *really* want to check whether an argument was passed in or not, then the only reliable way to do this is to check arguments.length:

```
this.setCurrent = function (intValue) {
   if (arguments.length === 0) {
     this.current = 0;
   }
   else {
     this.current = intValue;
   }
};
```

This seems pointless to me though. If the value is falsy, then it's clearly either 0 already or it's not a valid numeric value.

Comment: you beat me by 5 sec i deleted my answer :-P

Comment: but i guess typeof is better :-)

Comment: why don't `angular.isUndefined`?

Comment: @pankajparkar that can also be used :-)

Comment: @pankajparkar Because it's more verbose without any actual benefit in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof` or `angular.isUndefined(intValue)` not `null` :-)

```
this.setCurrent = function (intValue) {
       if (typeof intValue=='undefined') { //if(angular.isUndefined(intValue))
         this.current = 0;
       }
       else {
         this.current = intValue;
       }
    };
```

In better way :-)

```
  this.setCurrent = function (intValue) {
           if (typeof intValue!='undefined') { //if(!angular.isUndefined(intValue))
             this.current = intValue;
           }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check variable is undefined or not using method provided by angular i.e. `angular.isDefined()` / `angular.isUndefined()` (Preferring check with angular way)

```
this.setCurrent = function (intValue) {
   if (angular.isDefined(intValue)) {
     this.current = 0;
   }
   else {
     this.current = intValue;
   }
};
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary || operator...

```js
app.controller('GalleryController', function(){
    this.current = 0;
    this.setCurrent = function(pas_value) {
      this.current = pas_value || 0;
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one more way to do the same:

```
app.controller('GalleryController', function(){
    this.current = 0;
    this.setCurrent = function(intValue){
      this.current = intValue || 0;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('GalleryController', function(){
  this.current = 0;
  this.setCurrent = function(checkCurrent) {
    this.current = checkCurrent || 0;
  };
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.